# HTML Reload Dropdown Value JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I Have a script like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<select id="first" onchange="deleteitem()">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
</select><br >
<select id="second" >
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    <option value="6">Six</option>
    <option value="7">Seven</option>
    <option value="8">Eight</option>
    <option value="9">Nine</option>
</select><br >

<script>
    var one = document.getElementById('first');
    var two = document.getElementById('second');

    function deleteitem() {
        for(var i = one.selectedIndex; i >= 0; i--){
            two.remove(i);
            for(var x = one.length;x>=one.selectedIndex+5;x--) {
                two.remove(x);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When user change first dropdown, it will remove some items in second dropdown.

My question is: how can I reload second dropdown when I select first dropdown without refreshing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already answered here

```
function bindDdl() {
            try {
                var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl1');
                var x = PageMethods.GetData('', onsuccess, onfail);
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
        function onsuccess(result) {
            try {
                var ddl = document.getElementById('ddl1');
                var count= ddl.options.length;
                while (ddl.options.length > 0) {
                    ddl.options.remove(0);
                }

                for (var i = 0; i < result.length-1; i=i+2) {
                    var opt = document.createElement("option");

                    // Assign text and value to Option object
                    opt.text = result[i];
                    opt.value = result[i+1];
                    ddl.options.add(opt);
                }
            }
            catch (e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        }
```

You can have the onchange event like this

[Take a look at here](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

So you can reload it but

**NOTE :- if you are binding server side controls at client side it will always give you an error
Instead bind them on server side and add values at client side its preferable**

Comment: What is the purpose of the count variable?

Comment: @ribs2spare you can ignore that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to :

```
function reload() {
    var two = document.getElementById('second');
    // clear the select with id="two"
    two.innerHTML = "";
    // re-add the options
    var words = new Array("One", "Two", "Three", "Four" ... ); // fill it up yourself
    for(var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = words[i-1];
      option.value = i;
      two.appendChild(option);
    }
}
```