# Reload dropdown after adding values from popup page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have been trying all the Javascript options to reload a `dropdown`. I have a main page, I have 7 MySQL filled dropdowns, I have a link to open a new popup window with a java function, shown here:

```
function OpenWindowCourse() {
    window.open('Script/NewCourse.php', 'newwindow', config = 'height=150,width=370, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
    return true;
}
```

I use this to open a page with a form to upload new values to the course table, all working, when I submit form the popup closes, and returns to the main page, this issue is the course drop down needs to re populated with added value, I have to press f5 or refresh the page to see the new value in the drop down. I have tried every answer I have found (2 hours of looking and trying) to programmatically refresh the main page after the popup page is submitted. The site is written in `php` and`MySQL` database backend

---

Sorry some of the code was omitted.
I think I did not explain, here is the code on the main /  start page, it is filled in a php page with a link using a java script to open a popup second php page, it is a dynamically filled dropdown as the data is pulled from a included php data script that fills the drop down. please see:

     `echo "<select name='CourseIDdd' id='ddCourseID' style='width: 250px !important; max-width: 350px;'>\n";
     $resultout4 = get_course_rows();//call to data fuction php page, MySQL data
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($resultout4))
         {
         if ($row[0] == $CourseID)
             {
                echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "' selected='selected'>" . $row[1] . "</option>\n";
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "<option value='" . $row[0] . "'>" . $row[1] . "</option>\n";
            }
         }//while
     echo "</select>";
     echo '<a target="popup" onclick="OpenWindowModalCourse()">new</a>';`
this is the java call to open the popup course window that allows the user to add items to the table that fills the dropdown.
      `function OpenWindowModalCourse() {
      window.open('Script/NewCourse.php', 'newwindow', config = 'height=150,width=370, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no,location=no, directories=no, status=no');
      return true;
  }`

My issue is that when the NewCourse.php is closed, I need to refresh the first page as the data has been changed by the NewCourse.php page. So the user has to press f5 or refresh to be able to see the newly added value to the course table. There must be a way to force the first window to refresh when the post event has been processed on the Newcourse page. This has not been answered anywhere that I have seen, this is why I am asking. as the dropdown is not java filled or filled by procedure code, it differs from the provided answers. Thank you for the previous answers, but I don't see how they apply

Comment: does your solution require using another window for your form, or could you do it in a dialog overlaying the page you want to update?

Comment: Have a look at this solution from @just-code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21820330/html-reload-dropdown-value-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the parent from the child window, for example, your parent window contains the following code:

```
function repopulateCourses() {
    // add new dropdown options
}
```

And in the child window, the new window that you opened, you could do the following

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    window.opener.repopulateCourses();
};
```

Comment: Would this not expose my database code in the java window, I wrote the second popup as it is populated from the MySQL database table course, As stated there are 6 other tables that have corresponding drop-downs, I was hoping for a page refresh event from the post event on the popup entry window, the driving page is an entry page for MySQL table that has normalized tables to 7 lookup tables, hence the 7 drop downs. Am I looking at this wrong? It's just an annoyance that I have to have the client refresh the page to get the populated changes, as the changes are in a table in the database.

Comment: can I not refresh the main driving page from a java function on the popup page during the post event?